# missing operation in swagger-ui

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a spring boot application, And i have configured swagger with following configuration

maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then configuration for docket.

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
.paths(PathSelectors.any())
.build();
}
```

Now in my controller i have many end points , but intrestingly i see random behavior in swagger-ui, some endpoints are missing,

Issue : out of below 3 endpoints , i see only1 of them at once and restarting server shows changes behavior and i only see 1 of 3 endpoints.

1>

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}/addresses/{addressid}", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "action=register")
```

2>

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}/addresses/{addressid}", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "action=unregister")
```

3>

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}/addresses/{addressid}", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "action=deactivateAddress")
```

I just opened a issue [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1996).

Comment: My guess is that this isn't on Swagger's fault, but this is probably caused by either Springfox or your code. Can you tell us what version of Springfox you're using?

Comment: thanks for responding so fast. edited my qn , i m using 2.6.0..